# update one column with data from other column different table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to update a column from one table to the column in another table. Both columns have the same name and same ID and are populated. I need to update only IDs which match in both tables ( column id)
So for example all values from table_1 in column_x to be copied to table_2 in column_x if both are with same column_id

Fixed with help from other site.

Comment: please format this creature

Comment: tried: UPDATE table1
       JOIN table2
       ON column1.column_x = table2.column_x
SET    table2.id = table1.id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tried: UPDATE table1 JOIN table2 ON column1.column_x = table2.column_x SET table2.id = table1.id;

It looks like you've mixed up which column to join on and which column to copy. Your stated problem is:

> all values from table_1 in column_x to be copied to table_2 in column_x if both are with same column_id

The query to do this would be the following:

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id
SET table2.column_x = table1.column_x;
```

Or slightly more concisely:

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN table2 USING (column_id)
SET table2.column_x = table1.column_x;
```